# how to install inputmask on rails 6 with webpacker using jquery dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to install inputmask on Rails 6 via webpacker. Currently getting following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $el.inputmask is not a function
```

current setup, compiles with not issues.

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
require("jquery")
require("inputmask")
require("inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask");
require("inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions");
require("inputmask/dist/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions");
require("inputmask/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask");
```

config/webpack/alias.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
    "./dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib": "./dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib.jquery",
    }
  }
}
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const aliasConfig = require("./alias")
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.config.merge(aliasConfig)

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

I have seen quite a few examples out there but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common setup for jquery is to install it with yarn:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Then in environment.js

```
(...)

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}));

(...)
```

No need for `require("jquery")` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

Inputmask install:

```
yarn add inputmask
```

In `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
import 'inputmask';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
require("inputmask").default
```